# How to call merged dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, class-library

I have merged two dll a.dll and b.dll into one (merged.dll), now i want to use this dll in my project by typing `using merged.dll;`, also have pass the reference but it is giving me an error that

`type or namespace merged could not be found(...)`

I know I can add the reference of merged.dll in the project and use a.dll and b.dll separately but i want to add merged.dll and use all the methods and classes of a and b without calling them like `using a.dll;` and `using b.dll;` and I have also check the .net framework version of my project and the merged dll both are same, and I am using visual studio IDE.

And I have used *ILMerge* to merge the dll's.

kindly suggest me the solutions how can I fix this.

Best Regards,

Comment: Which utility  you have used to merge dlls ?ilmerg?

Comment: yes yes ilmerge

Comment: https://theburningmonk.com/2014/02/c-extern-alias-and-ilmerged-assemblies/

in this article he is doing it i don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ILMerge does not change namespaces, it will do repackaging of existing code into a single assembly file.
So
             using Merged;
will not work.

Solution 
1)You would need to use the original namespaces from the unmerged 
using A;
using B;

or 
2) Using Aliases as you shared

Comment: ok i change the alias to merge from global now how can i call the alias in my code?

Comment: extern alias merged? like this?